# Creating a string variable with specific spacing (using \t) similar to Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, string, console.writeline

How I could make this (broken) piece of code work:

```
aString = ("{0}\t{1}  \t{2}\t{3}", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
```

The string would take different elements from an array and put them into a new string which was formatted with the spacing shown above if it were to be produced through `Console.WriteLine` (which in this instance, since the array is calculated external to the main method, is not suitable.)

This string would then be returned and passed back to the main method. Is there a way to create a string with specific spacing such as the above in an easy manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, like so:

```
aString = String.Format("{0}\t{1}  \t{2}\t{3}", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
```

Comment: Note that `\t` does not provide "spacing" by itself - it will only appear when you output to console/file. If you need fixed width format you'd need to pad with spaces or use width specifiers of string format.